# Styling drop down center the options for select tag in chrome and firefox

Tags: php, html, css

I have a drop down list which I styled but I still can't get  why does the text always align differently in chrome and in firefox. I tried adding `text-align:center;` on my css and the firefox make the selection list centered but is not centered vertically while in chrome it doesn't centered it all but at least it's verticall alignment is centered. Here's the output of it currently (text-align center part removed):

Firefox rendering: 
[image]

Chrome rendering: 
[image: for chrome]

this is my css code so far:

div container for the dropdown:

```
.container {
 background-color:#424141;
 border:1px solid #424141;
 width:280px;
  height:40px;
  font-size:13pt;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-right: -20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

and for the drop down:

```
.dropdown  {
 background-color:#424141;
  border:1px solid #424141;
  position:absolute;
  color: #000000;
  width:280px;
  height:40px;
  font-size:13pt;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

and here's the result after adding `text-align:center;` on the dropdown class:

[image: result 2]

in chrome it remains the same as above.

Here's the html code for this. well it's inside a table I think I can just skip the other part:

```
<tr>
    <td><p class="titles">City</p></td>
    <td><div class="container"><select name="city" tabindex="16" class="dropdown">
        <?php foreach ($cities as $city1): ?>

            <option <?php echo "value='".$city1['city']."'"; if($city1['city']==$city){echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>
        <?php echo $city1['city']; ?>
            </option>

        <?php endforeach ?>
        </select></div></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do cannot be done cross-browser using HTML/CSS because the HTML/CSS specification doesn't actually SAY how CSS or styling is supposed to be applied to form elements. Actualy you can write your own dropdown with javascript:

html:

```
<div id="search_result_fake_container">
    <input id="search_result_fake" value="- All Categories -">
    <div id="search_result_fake_div"></div>
</div>
<div id="search_result_present_list">
    <div class="search_result_list_item" id="search_result_item_1" style="text-align:center;">item1</div>';
    <div class="search_result_list_item" id="search_result_item_2" style="text-align:center;">item2</div>';
    <div class="search_result_list_item" id="search_result_item_3" style="text-align:center;">item3</div>';
</div>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search_result_fake_div").live("click", function () {
            $("#search_result_present_list").show("fast");
        });

        $("#search_result_present_list").live("mouseleave", function () {
            $("#search_result_present_list").hide();
        });

        $(".search_result_list_item").live("click", function () {
            $("#search_result_fake").val($(this).html());
            $("#search_result_present_list").hide();
        });
    })
</script>
```

css:

```
#search_result_fake {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* for Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* for Safari $ Chrome */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* for IE $ Opera */
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 90%;
    outline: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 100%;
}

#search_result_fake_div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#search_result_present_list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 85px;
    left: 65%;
    font-size: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #eae7e7;
    border: #6f6f6f solid 1px;;
    height: 190px;
    width: 23%;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

css is copy paste but i hope you understand what i meen

Comment: I see, I've heard about the dropkick as a solution for this one but hell, I can't understand how it actually works! Their page doesn't give a clear documentation on how to use it and given the point that I'm not that well versed in javascript and jQuery this is really troublesome. Anyway I'll still try finding an alternate solution.

Comment: ok, i can give you sample what i wrote... whaite a minute pls

Comment: I got it man! now all I need to do is to add some styling for this one. Now I think learning how to use jQuery cannot be avoided anymore. Well I think I'd give it a try now that I see what greatness it can do. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Hi John, last question. Sorry since I'm not that familiar with jQuery. Well I've resized your work to appear exactly as my design but I noticed that whenever I clicked on the whole page the lists appears. I'm positive that this triggers due to jQuery. how can I make sure that the list only appears when I clicked the input or the search_result_fake_container div container?

Comment: this dropdown must shown when you click on the search_result_fake_div element, this element should be placed directly on the  search_result_fake input, try to watch in firebug search_result_fake_div size, and you will known click area

Comment: oh, got it.  just re-sized the div on the css. Anyway I just wonder, why does it doesn't work if I make the jQuery listen to search_result_fake instead of the fake_div? I just think that it would be more convenient that way.

Comment: No, search_result_fake_div used to prevent the user from clicking on the input and change text, if you make the jQuery listen to search_result_fake that will work by clicking on the search_result_fake but not on the input.

Comment: Ohh, bunch of new informations comes to me. Many thanks to you. :)